# MkAnnotation drop animation iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I try to animate my custom MkAnnotation, it works great on iOS 5 but not on iOS 6. Here is my didAddAnnotationViews method :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)annotationViews
{
    NSTimeInterval delayInterval = 0;

    for (MKAnnotationView *annView in annotationViews)
    {
        // Don't pin drop if annotation is user location
        if ([annView.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
            continue;
        }

        // Check if current annotation is inside visible map rect, else go to next one
        MKMapPoint point =  MKMapPointForCoordinate(annView.annotation.coordinate);
        if (!MKMapRectContainsPoint(self.mapView.visibleMapRect, point)) {
            continue;
        }

        CGRect endFrame = annView.frame;

        // Move annotation out of view
        annView.frame = CGRectMake(annView.frame.origin.x, annView.frame.origin.y - self.view.frame.size.height, annView.frame.size.width, annView.frame.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:delayInterval
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         annView.frame = endFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             if (isModal)
                                 [self.mapView selectAnnotation:[[self.mapView annotations]     objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
                         }];

        delayInterval += 0.0625;
    }
}
```

I made this method with some parts of code i found on internet. On iOS 5 the animation is perfect, but on iOS 6 pins are just appearing without any kind of animation. Setting the mapView delegate is the first thing I do on my viewDidLoad, and i've also tried to generate my annotations from viewDidAppear method , without success.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

**EDIT : Solution found, I use the perform:withObject:afterDelay: method and it seems to work.**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [self performSelector:@selector(addAnnotation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)addAnnotation
{
    MapViewAnnotation *annotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" andCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(49.6, 6.2)];
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, look at the edit section.